# Replace Vimeo and Youtube in from scratch theme with from-the-group-up single post template?

Tags: customization, oembed

I've inherited a theme that uses a totally in-house post display, and doesn't use the post loop. My question is, what function do I have to feed my post content object through in order to use oEmbed to replace the YouTube and Vimeo links in the post body with the oEmbed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [`WP_Embed::autoembed()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_embed/autoembed/). Try:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array( 'WP_Embed', 'autoembed' ) );
```

in your theme's `functions.php` file.